# How to create a function that subtracts the current value from previous value every time it's called

Tags: python, json

I am querying a dataset that works like this: each time I query it produces a different value of `Bytes_Written` and `Bytes_Read`. What I cannot seem to accomplish is to subtract the current value from the previous value and keep doing this every second.

Here is what the data looks like:

```
{
  "Number of Devices": 2,
  "Block Devices": {
    "bdev0": {
      "Backend_Device_Path": "/dev/disk/by-path/ip-192.168.26.1:3260-iscsi-iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-d1c8e7c6-8c77-444c-9a93-8b56fa1e37f2-lun-010.0.0.142",
      "Capacity": "2147483648",
      "Guest_Device_Name": "vdb",
      "IO_Operations": "97069",
      "Bytes_Written": "34410496",
      "Bytes_Read": "363172864"
    },
    "bdev1": {
      "Backend_Device_Path": "/dev/disk/by-path/ip-192.168.26.1:3260-iscsi-iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-b27110f9-41ba-4bc6-b97c-b5dde23af1f9-lun-010.0.0.146",
      "Capacity": "2147483648",
      "Guest_Device_Name": "vdb",
      "IO_Operations": "93",
      "Bytes_Written": "0",
      "Bytes_Read": "380928"
    }
  }
}
```

The code that queries the data:

```
def counterVolume_one():
    #Get data 
    url = 'http://url:8080/vrio/blk'
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

wanted = {'Bytes_Written', 'Bytes_Written', 'IO_Operation'}
for d in data['Block Devices'].itervalues():
    values = {k: v for k, v in d.iteritems() if k in wanted}
    print json.dumps(values)

counterVolume_one()
```

The way I want to get the output is:

```
{"IO_Operations": "97069", "Bytes_Read": "363172864", "Bytes_Written": "34410496"}
{"IO_Operations": "93", "Bytes_Read": "380928", "Bytes_Written": "0"}
```

Here is what I want to accomplish:

```
first time query = first set of values
after 1 sec
second time query = first set of values-second set of values
after 1 sec
third time query = second set of  values-third set of values
```

Expected output would be a json object as below

```
{'bytes-read': newvalue, 'bytes-written': newvalue, 'io_operations': newvalue}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me -- what exactly is getting larger with each query?

Comment: It’s also unclear to me what you’re struggling with. You surely can create three variables for those values and subtract them, no?

Comment: @poke: you are write but how too accomplish it so that the function does not starts from the very beginning every time I query but  takes values from the previous

Comment: Using a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) perhaps?

Comment: @Emilgardis: would be real help if you could show  an example with my data?

Comment: @Imo could **you** produce an expected output with your data? I have no idea what format you want your output in! Is that a dict? a JSON object? a string?

Comment: @AdamSmith I want a json object like so {'bytes-read': newvalue, 'bytes-written': newvalue, 'io_operations': newvalue} and then the next one same like this format but with new values

Comment: @iLoveTux: you are right the request call should be inside the function

Comment: @iLoveTux: I dont see your answer anymore below

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I misunderstood your question and my answer was just plain wrong. Then I had to go home, after I get the kids to sleep I will post a better answer. Sorry for the inconvenience. The answer from Willi Ballenthin is correct, if he doesn't get around to it I will post a solution involving a state-machine class.

Comment: @iLoveTux Wills example is correct but it produces the data in a wrong format, Bytes_Written: 34410496, Bytes_Read: 0, IO_Operation: 0
while I need 
{Bytes_Written: 103231488, Bytes_Read: 0, IO_Operation: 0}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest fix may be to modify the `counterVolume_one()` function so that it accepts parameters that define the current state, and that you'd update as you collect data. For example, the following code collects and sums the the fields your interested in from the JSON documents:

```
FIELDS = ('Bytes_Written', 'Bytes_Read', 'IO_Operation')

def counterVolume_one(state):
    url = 'http://url:8080/vrio/blk'
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

    for field in FIELDS:
        state[field] += data[field]
    return state

state = {"Bytes_Written": 0, "Bytes_Read": 0, "IO_Operation": 0}
while True:
    counterVolume_one(state)
    time.sleep(1)
    for field in FIELDS:
        print("{field:s}: {count:d}".format(field=field,
                                            count=state[field]))
```

A more correct fix might be to use a class to hold the state, and that has a method that updates the state. But, I think following the idea above will get you the solution quickest.

Comment: thank you will for your answer it gives the following error   counterVolume_one(state)
TypeError: counterVolume_one() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: I fixed the error but its now returns data with wrong format I need the format to be {Bytes_written: value, Bytes_read: value, IO_operations:value}